# Does or Will MS Allow changing the Masterpage in SP2016 on-Prem?

Tags: custom-masterpage

I know that you cannot do this in O365 but what about on-Prem for SharePoint 2016. Will Service Packs or CU's break my Masterpage if its customized?  What should be the best practice.

Bismarck

Answer (score 3):

You can change it in SPO, the risk is that you won't receive updates as Microsoft releases them.

The same risk applies on prem, but you have more control over the process. The general guidance is to not touch the master page, but apply CSS and JavaScript customizations instead. If you do customize the master page, know your risks, and test Service pack and CU upgrades and fix as necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I want to future proof my branding if I can.  Its seems CSS and JavaScript are the way to go.

Comment: Correct, Vesa has stated many times this is the best practice, CSS/JS, but like any best practice there are always exceptions. Just know your risks and plan accordingly in that case.